# .click() event in Safari different than actual click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, safari

I'm trying to trigger a button's click event when a user pushes Enter from a textbox. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
                alert("Hello");   
                $("#<%= lbSearch.ClientID %>").click();
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSearch" runat="server" onclick="lbSearch_Click" />
```

All my click event does it redirect to a different page.

When I click on the button, it works. When I push Enter from the textbox in IE, Firefox, or Chrome, it works.

But when I push Enter in Safari, the page just performs a postback, even though the jQuery function gets hit (the alert shows).

Any reason for this?

Comment: What does doing this do? `$(function(){ $("#<%= lbSearch.ClientID %>").click(); });`

Comment: @KevinB - it triggers the click event in every browser except Safari, which for some reason just performs a postback

Comment: ... That's very odd. a js triggered click shouldn't be doing a postback unless you have a handler on the click that causes the postback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run `e.preventDefault();` after determining that it is the enter key.  Otherwise, the form posts before the javascript gets a chance to finish running.

Comment: I added that right before my alert. Now the alert shows, but the page doesn't postback or redirect at all. It seems like it's recognizing I hit Enter, but it's not performing the click event.

Comment: @Steven try `$(...).trigger('click')`

Comment: @JanDvorak - same result unfortunately, the alert shows and then nothing happens.

Comment: @Steven I was solving a similar issue before and ended up performing the default action manually.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by object method:

```
function RaiseClickEvent(id) {
  var clickObject = {
    click : document.getElementById(id).onclick
  };
  clickObject.click();
}

var id = "<%= lbSearch.ClientID %>";
RaiseClickEvent(id);
```